# Fetch parent class data from static method

Tags: php, oop, php-5.2

In an existing code base, I have a static builder method that returns an instance. Here's a simplified example:

```
class Grandparent{
}

class Parent extends Grandparent{
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public static fetchChildById($id){
        // ...
        return new Child;
    }
}
```

In real code I have a single `Grandparent` class and several subclasses similar to `Parent` and `Child` (not just `Parent` and `Child`).

I now need to implement a new method at `Grandparent` to be used at `fetchChildById()`. Such method needs to make use of certain piece of data that's common to all children from the same parent. Since I don't have a class instance yet I'm forced to make everything static but, of course, that won't work properly because it isn't possible to overrite static properties and methods:

```
class Grandparent{
    protected static $data = array(
        'default',
    );

    protected static function filter(){
        foreach(self::$data as $i){ // <!-- Will always be `default'
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class Parent extends Grandparent{
    protected static $data = array(
        'one',
        'two',
    );
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public static fetchChildById($id){
        self::filter();
        // ...
        return new Child;
    }
}
```

I believe it's a use case for late static binding *but* code needs to run on PHP/5.2.0 :(

I'm not very fond of the obvious workarounds I've thought about:

- Creating a separate builder class suggest more refacting than I can afford at this time:

  ```
  $builder = new ChildBuilder;
  $bart = $builder->fetchChildById(1);
  ```
- Creating additional instances looks ugly (and implies many changes as well):

  ```
  $builder = new Child;
  $bart = $builder->fetchChildById(1);
  ```
- Global variables... Oh well, I'm not so desperate yet.

Am I overlooking some obvious mechanism to customize `$data`?

Comment: Tight spot. Did you consider variations of workaround #2? At first sight it seems `fetchChildById` will need to create an instance of the called class anyway; why not use that instance to buy virtual method calls inside `fetchChildById` itself?

Comment: What about some `debug_backtrace`?

Comment: @Jon - Egg and chicken. Data is needed to create the instance. And I can't easily create a dummy instance because of mandatory arguments in constructor.

Comment: @sectus - Yeah... Could work if I figure out the details... I'm working on a variation of that, I'll report back if I go somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative using reflection. It will require modification of all `fetchChildById` implementations, but it's trivial enough to be done with global find/replace:

```
self::filter(__CLASS__); // this is the modification
```

Then `filter` would become:

```
protected static function filter($className){
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $data = $reflect->getStaticPropertyValue('data');
    foreach($data as $i){
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Update:** The property `$data` needs to be public for the above to work (apologies -- I wrote `public` during exploration). But there's an equivalent version that doesn't have this requirement:

```
$reflect = new ReflectionProperty($className, 'data');
$reflect->setAccessible(true);
$data = $reflect->getValue();
```

Comment: Absolutely feasible. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: After a little more tinkering it seems you can use `get_class_vars` and fish `$data` out of that as an alternative to reflection. Might be faster, no idea. Glad to help.

Comment: Confirmed: `getStaticPropertyValue()` does work. In my case I need to use `get_parent_class()` instead of `__CLASS__` but property needs to be `public`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: You can work around the `public` requirement easily -- updated the answer with reflection code, `get_class_vars` should work out of the box as long as you are calling it inside `Grandparent` because it takes the current scope into account. But why do you need to use `get_parent_class`?